# Why do code snippets need cookies?

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets

Testing the answer to question that involves cookies and should behave differently if cookies are disabled, I just found out something weird:

When you disable cookies, code snippets won't work any more , the buttons `Run code snippet` and `Copy snippet to answer` won't be displayed.

That made me wonder: Why are cookies even needed for this to work?

Comment: because they get hungry

Comment: I only work off cookies and coffee. Give me both and I'll work, too :)

Comment: The answers in the comments are very funny, but would be nice to have also a real one.